# How would I recognize the noise of a clap in an iPhone application?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-audio, audioqueueservices

Within my iPhone application, how would I recognize the noise that a clap makes?

Comment: Clap recognition? What is that?

Comment: I want to make iphone app to find missing iphone in a room when I clap 3 times I phone shud detect clap and speaks i m here ..

Comment: user553239: Keep in mind that the user will have to have the foresight to start your application before losing their phone.

Comment: @peter or you could keep it always on, which would eat battery up and kill the phone sooner than you could start clapping.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're talking about recognizing the sound of a clap, [SCListener](https://github.com/stephencelis/sc_listener) is a great and easy-to-use class that gives you simple audio levels. Then it's just a question of measuring peaks or even just high values.

Comment: user553239: It's a class of object that listens on the microphone and lets you retrieve the peak and average sound level. A clap will be a high peak that then drops back down to background-noise level. Use of the class is described in the readme at the bottom of the page Luke linked you to.

Comment: Thanks  a lot Luke and Peter :) I would try  to use this in my project.

Comment: Is there any delegate for this class? @Luke